# Arranging nested tuples

Tags: list, sorting, python-3.x, tuples

I know that this is probably a silly question and I apologize for that, but I am very new to python and have tried to solve this for a long time now, with no success. 
I have a list of tuples similar to the one bellow:

```
data = [('ralph picked', ['nose', '4', 'apple', '30', 'winner', '3']), 
('aaron popped', ['soda', '1', 'popcorn', '6', 'pill', '4', 'question', '29'])]
```

I would like to sort the nested list in descending other:

```
data = [('ralph picked', ['apple', '30', 'nose', '4', 'winner', '3']), 
('aaron popped', ['question', '29', 'popcorn', '6', 'pill', '4', 'soda', '1'])]
```

I tried using simple

```
sorted(data)
```

but what I get is only the first item of tuple sorted. What I am missing here? I really thank you for any help.

Comment: I would NOT call it sorting. What you are doing is **Arranging**

Comment: Why does `4` appear once in the first line of the first example, but twice in the first line of the second example? No amount of sorting will turn a six element list into a seven element one.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks kevin, it was a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Thanks for the clarification, as I said, new to python, this sort of comment helps.

Comment: That is exactly why I made it, to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider only the inner list.  The first issue is that it seems like you want to keep word, number pairs together.  We can use `zip` to combine them, remembering that `seq[::2]` gives us every second element starting at the 0th, and `seq[1::2]` gives us every second starting at the first:

```
>>> s = ['nose', '4', 'apple', '30', 'winner', '3']
>>> zip(s[::2], s[1::2])
<zip object at 0xb5e996ac>
>>> list(zip(s[::2], s[1::2]))
[('nose', '4'), ('apple', '30'), ('winner', '3')]
```

Now, as you've discovered, if you call `sorted` on a sequence, it sorts first by the first element, then by the second to break ties, etc., going as deep as it needs to.  So if we call `sorted` on this:

```
>>> sorted(zip(s[::2], s[1::2]))
[('apple', '30'), ('nose', '4'), ('winner', '3')]
```

Well, that looks like it works, but only by fluke because `apple-nose-winner` is in alphabetical order.  Really we want to sort by the second term.  `sorted` takes a `key` parameter:

```
>>> sorted(zip(s[::2], s[1::2]), key=lambda x: x[1])
[('winner', '3'), ('apple', '30'), ('nose', '4')]
```

That didn't work either, because it's sorting the number strings lexicographically (dictionary-style, so '30' comes before '4').  We can tell it we want to use the numerical value, though:

```
>>> sorted(zip(s[::2], s[1::2]), key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
[('winner', '3'), ('nose', '4'), ('apple', '30')]
```

Almost there -- we want this reversed:

```
>>> sorted(zip(s[::2], s[1::2]), key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)
[('apple', '30'), ('nose', '4'), ('winner', '3')]
```

And this is almost right, but we need to flatten it.  We can use either a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> s2 = sorted(zip(s[::2], s[1::2]), key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)
>>> [value for pair in s2 for value in pair]
['apple', '30', 'nose', '4', 'winner', '3']
```

or use `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(s2))
['apple', '30', 'nose', '4', 'winner', '3']
```

And I think that's where we wanted to go.

Comment: Wow, this was very clear and didactic, thank you. I am sorry, though, because I don't know how to adapt your answer to my existing list. I am probably missing something, but I really need to keep the inner list inside the bigger one. Any tips on how to make this work to my existing list, with the nested part?

Comment: That's pretty simple.  Do you know how to loop over a list and modify an element by index?

Comment: I was able to create the loop, but now I am getting a error message at the line `sorted(zip(s[::2], s[1::2]), key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)`, it says `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'`. I tried replacing `int` but with no success. Any ideas on how this can be? I really appreciate.